# Adding divs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I request your help in this problem.
I have a javascript code and a div that displays a status when the user clicks a particular button.
My problem is: how add this div modal javascript?

```
function openstatus(){
    $.modal({
        content: 'DIV CONTENT'
        buttons: {
            'Fechar': {
                classes:'huge blue-gradient glossy full-width',
                click:function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
            }
        },
        buttonsLowPadding: true
    });
};
```

I need to put 3 divs there in "div content"`<div id="log-contente"></div> <div id="log-sistema-conteudo"></div><div id="log-sistema-content-back"></div>`
How would the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div and set its innerHtml to the content you need to add, something like this (i didn't try it but it should work):

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.innerHtml = "<div id="log-contente"></div><div id="log-sistema-conteudo"></div><div id="log-sistema-content-back"></div>";
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the three div's into a parent div and launch the parent div in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function openstatus(){
    var divContent = '<div id="log-contente"></div><div id="log-sistema-conteudo"></div><div id="log-sistema-content-back"></div>';
    $.modal({
        content: divContent,
        buttons: {
            'Fechar': {
                classes:'huge blue-gradient glossy full-width',
                click:function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
            }
        },
        buttonsLowPadding: true
    });
};
```